# Проблема с установкой модуля pytelegrambotapi

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot, pip, python-3.8

Модуль не скачивается:

```
  pip install pyTelegramBotAPI
Collecting pyTelegramBotAPI
  Using cached pyTelegramBotAPI-3.7.6.tar.gz (81 kB)
    ERROR: Error [WinError 87] Параметр задан неверно while executing command python setup.py egg_info
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 87] Параметр задан неверно

WARNING: You are using pip version 20.1.1; however, version 21.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Насколько я понимаю, здесь требуется обновить питон?

Comment: Попробуйте pip обновить, вам же пишут, что версия устаревшая.

Comment: https://translate.google.ru/?sl=en&tl=ru&text=WARNING%3A%20You%20are%20using%20pip%20version%2020.1.1%3B%20however%2C%20version%2021.0.1%20is%20available.%0AYou%20should%20consider%20upgrading%20via%20the%20%27c%3A%5Cusers%5Clenovo%5Cappdata%5Clocal%5Cprograms%5Cpython%5Cpython38-32%5Cpython.exe%20-m%20pip%20install%20--upgrade%20pip%27%20command.%0A&op=translate

Comment: `pip freeze` работает ?